# Managing users with OPA

Tags: authentication, opa

How can I manage users with Opa ? I've seen that there is a CLogin module, but I don't see how it works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a very generic question -- what do you exactly mean with "managing users"? CLogin module is a graphical widget that will display login/passwd boxes and then it's parametrized by a function that does authentication. So it's just the graphical part of the login system; password verification, storing etc. have to be coded elsewhere. For using it -- did you try to read the documentation in the module?

I can try to provide more accurate answer if you can make the question more specific.

Comment: In fact, I want to do two things :

1- Support user login in my application, i.e. use login/passwd to authenticate users.
2- I want to have separate database for each users  

How can I do that ? Can session helps me to do that ? It seems that I need a way to create variables that are unique for each logged user.

Thanks,

Comment: I may be missing something but I have found the documentation on this module very scarce. A good tutorial of how to leverage the module may be worth while. Do you know of any documentation that I may of missed?